# My LinearSystemPlot function keeps disappearing when using with(Student[LinearAlgebra])

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, maple

I use Maple to plot my matrices, i use the package:

```
with(Student[LinearAlgebra]) :
infolevelStudent[LinearAlgebra] := 1 :
```

the function `LinearSystemPlot(...)` exist sometimes and other times don't. The `infolevelStudent[LinearAlgebra] := 1 :`  doesn't print out the information about the package as it is suppose to do either. Have anyone experience with similar behavior from Maple? i think it's just so weird when it sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't - makes it impossible to work with consistently.

The part of the package under the namespace `LinearAlgebra` usually works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for the second statement is invalid. You need to index `infolevel` on the left-hand-side. It should be either,

```
infolevel[Student:-LinearAlgebra] := 1:
```

or,

```
infolevel[Student[LinearAlgebra]] := 1:
```

You can generally use `Student:-LinearAlgebra` instead of `Student[LinearAlgebra]` in both. I prefer the first, and it's somewhat unfortunate that so many Help example use the alternate syntax, IMO. Note that wasn't the reason why your `infolevel` attempt failed.

So your first statement would then be,

```
with(Student:-LinearAlgebra):
```

Note that if you intend on calling `LinearSystemPlot(...)` in that short form then you always need to reload the package after any `restart`. Your intermittent results might be due to your doing a restart without a reload of the package. You haven't given us code that reproduces your intermittent failure of the call to `LinearSystemPlot`, though, or said what was actually returned when it didn't work.

Also, make sure that you don't end a statement with a call to `LinearSystemPlot` with a full colon, if you expect to see a result. The full colon suppresses output from a statement from being displayed.

You should *always* be able to access the command with its fully qualified "long form", ie,

```
:-Student:-LinearAlgebra:-LinearSystemPlot(...);
```

or (if you haven't written your own Student package),

```
Student:-LinearAlgebra:-LinearSystemPlot(...);
```

You might have been having difficulty in reading and copying the examples from the Help page in the (default) of 2D-Math input form. Note that the Help window has an icon at its top which allows you to toggle most examples from Help pages from typeset 2D Math input form to 1D Maple Notation (plaintext) form.